# ERROR: Module meteor can't get loaded. WebdriverIO

Tags: node.js, linux, meteor, mocha.js, webdriver-io

Recently we restarted our server:

```
Linux version 4.4.4-200.fc22.x86_64 (mockbuild@bkernel02.phx2.fedoraproject.org) (gcc version 5.3.1 20151207 (Red Hat 5.3.1-2) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Fri Mar 4 20:06:29 UTC 2016
```

When i try to run my tests with webdriverio, for my meteor app:

```
//scripts:{"wdio-test": "wdio tests/config/wdio.mocha.conf.js"}

meteor npm run wdio-tests
```

I get this Error:

```
ERROR: Module meteor can't get loaded. Are you sure you have installed it?
Note: if you've installed WebdriverIO globally you need to install these external modules globally too!
chrome
    at MochaAdapter.load (node_modules/wdio-mocha-framework/build/adapter.js:473:23)
    at wdio-mocha-framework/build/adapter.js:321:28
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at MochaAdapter.requireExternalModules (node_modules/wdio-mocha-framework/build/adapter.js:313:21)
    at MochaAdapter.options (node_modules/wdio-mocha-framework/build/adapter.js:139:18)
    at Suite.<anonymous> (node_modules/wdio-mocha-framework/build/adapter.js:171:43)
    at emitThree (events.js:102:20)
    at Suite.emit (events.js:175:7)
    at node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:230:11
    at Array.forEach (native)
```

These are my Versions:

```
meteor --version
Meteor 1.5.2.2

meteor node --version
v4.8.4

meteor npm --version
4.6.1

node --version
v6.11.2

npm --version
3.10.10
```

And the packages:

```
  "mocha": "^3.5.0",
  "mocha-mongoose": "^1.2.0",
  "mocha-reporter": "0.0.3",
  "mockery": "^2.1.0",
  "mongo-mock": "^2.5.0",
  "mongoose": "^4.12.0",
  "selenium-webdriver": "^3.0.0-beta-2",
  "wdio-mocha-framework": "^0.5.11",
  "webdriverio": "^4.8.0",
```

We recently did an upgrade from Meteor 1.3.5 to 1.5.2.2, but there was not a problem with the webdriver tests. Since the restart however i am getting the error mentioned above.

I have also not installed any packages globally.

Anyone knows how i can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found out i had this option inside my `wdio-mocha.conf`:

```
 mochaOpts: {
    ui: 'bdd',
    compilers: ['js:babel-register'],
    require: ['babel-polyfill', 'meteor'],
 },
```

removing the meteor tag solved the problem.

I will let this question open for a while, maybe someone has to add something.